# How do I call a function for any unhandled exception in my Flask app?

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask app that I am using to create some API endpoints (using `flask-restful`) for interacting with an app I am developing. I have built a function `error_handler.unhandled_exception` that is intended to text and email the developer any time an unhandled exception is thrown anywhere in the app. However, I don't know how to call this function!

So my question is this: **how can I call a specific function to run any time an unhandled exception is thrown in my Flask app??**

I tried the following:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        app.run()
    except Exception as exc:
        print("Caught an exception!")
        error_handler.unhandled_exception(exc)
        raise exc
```

Which isn't working as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try decorating all of your route functions:

```py
def handle_exceptions(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        except Exception as exc:
            print(f"Hey Dev! I caught '{type(exc).__name__}: {exc}'")
            raise exc
    return wrapper


@handle_exceptions
def some_route_function():
    print("User did something weird")
    raise ConnectionError("Oops!")


some_route_function()
```

Output:

```
User did something weird
Hey Dev! I caught 'ConnectionError: Oops!'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ....
ConnectionError: Oops!
```

Comment: Updated my post above to show what I tried - is this what you meant?

Comment: Ah yes that exactly what I was talking about. Is Flask doing something to handle its own exceptions?

Comment: this did the trick - thanks so much!